# Xcode beta 7.3 submission to iTunes Connect for TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, beta

I have been developing an iOS app on Xcode version 7.3 beta and need to submit my app to TestFlight. I found out that my submission to iTunes connect fails because I am using the beta version of Xcode. I would like to know if I can archive my app and upload using Xcode version 7.2?

Comment: Have you tried archiving and using Application Loader?

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload the apps to ITC built by beta versions of Xcode. You can try to upload app with Xcode 7.2.